# create custom unordered list from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, uiview, xib, addsubview

I'm trying to build a custom unordered list (with custom checkmarks as "bullets"). The data for this list is an `NSArray` containing `NSString`s.

My idea was to add multiple subviews (based on a xib file) to a UIView. The xib file has a `UIImageView` (checkmark) and a `UIlabel` (to set the text).

I tried to loop through the `NSArray`, and add a custom `UIView` to the list-container:

```
for (id line in currentDeal.dealDescriptionArray) {
    NSLog(line);

    CustomLineView *specView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customLineView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    specView.specLabel.text = line;
    [listContainer addSubview:specView];

}
```

However, this only shows the last item of the array, I think I'm just adding pointers to the same object, but I don't no how I create "new" instances.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new instances, you just aren't positioning them so they're all on top of each other (so effectively you only see the last one).

Either set the frame before adding as a subview or add constraints after adding as a subview so that the views are laid out appropriately. You can do this by increment img a counter in your loop to represent the position offset in the parent view.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That makes sense. The subviews can have different heights (when the string is too long, it will be over multiple lines). Therefor I guess I'll have to work with constraints. Should I create constraints between one subview and the previous one, or is it possible/better to get the height of each subview and calculate the position relative to the container?

Comment: Yes, best to have constraints between the views and allow the intrinsic content size to set the heights